# Rails 6 rake assets:precompile failing with Docker on AWS due to missing Master Key Env variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6 application with credentials running on Docker locally. 
In order to get this up and running on AWS ElasticBeanstalk, I want to precompile assets as part of the Docker build. However, as outlined on [this issue in the rails repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32947) , I get the following error on `rake assets:precompile`:

`Missing encryption key to decrypt file with. Ask your team for your master key and write it to config/master.key or put it in the ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY'].`

I have added the `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` as an environment variable on the EB environment (Configuration > Software > Modify) but during Docker build it does not read the Env variable from there.

What's the best and most secure way to allow Docker build to access Env variables? Should I run my `assets:precompile` before deploy instead?

Locally, I can get assets to precompile in production mode by passing the Key through as a build-arg (see part in Dockerfile where I parse the RAILS_MASTER_KEY argument and set it), however, this doesn't seem like the right option for production? Or if it is, how should I go about doing that?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3-slim
ARG RAILS_MASTER_KEY

bla bla install yarn etc

RUN gem install bundler
#Install gems
RUN mkdir /gems
WORKDIR /gems
COPY Gemfile .
COPY Gemfile.lock .
RUN bundle install

ARG INSTALL_PATH=/opt/my_app
ENV INSTALL_PATH $INSTALL_PATH
ENV RAILS_MASTER_KEY $RAILS_MASTER_KEY
WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
COPY . .

RUN RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

The master key you added is probably not correct. Check the master key in `config/master.key` (in local). Master keys must be the same in local and aws.

Also, make sure you add the master key in AWS. Enter the console and print the master key with `ENV['RAILS_MASTER_KEY']`.

Comment: Thanks, but the master key is definitely correct. That's not the issue in this case as I can see that the problem is the master key hasn't been set at all

Comment: To clarify - the issue is that the ENV variables are not available during `docker build` command. When I add `RUN env` to my Dockerfile and look at the output during the build (eb-activity.log), the RAILS_MASTER_KEY and other env variables are not present in the output, while other variables such as RUBY_VERSION and PATH etc are

Comment: @cash22 You can try the other way. Create `config/master.key` in AWS. Add master key to this file.

Comment: I don't know how I would go about incorporating that step securely into a solid set up and deploy workflow. Can you expand? Also, it doesn't explain why I am having this problem in the first place. I think it's more to do with Docker and env variables than issues with the EB instance, but perhaps I'm wrong. If you have a solid, proven suggestion I'd love to hear it

Comment: @cash22 I'm not sure how you can do this safely. Again it's best to do it with environment variable :) Can you share the part in Dockerfile where you added the environment variable?

Comment: If I ssh into my EB server (`eb ssh`) and run `env` or `printenv`, variables that are set in Configuration > Software > Modify are not listed. Does that seem correct? Running `eb printenv` locally does list them

Comment: Make sure you select Environment correctly. Check these steps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby.container.html
https://evrim.io/deploying-a-rails-52-postgresql-app-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/